# Elasticsearch bool filter with groovy api

Tags: groovy, elasticsearch

I have the next query:

```
GET /index/type/_search
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "match": {
          "project": "ABC"
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {"term": {
              "subtech": 2
            }},
            {
              "term": {
                "tech": 1
              }
            },
            {
              "term": {
                "country": 1
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }  
}
```

And the response has 50 hits. All is well because I have 100 documents with tech:1, country:1, and fifty fifty subtech: 1, subtech:2

When I write this query with the groovy api I has filtered with the last term value:
- last value subtech, hits = 50
- last value tech, hits = 100
- last value country, hits = 100

The query:

```
client.search {
            indices 'index'
            types 'type'
            source {
                query {
                    filtered {
                        query {
                            match(project: 'ABC')
                        }
                        filter {
                            bool {                                
                                must {
                                    term(subtech:2)                                    
                                }
                                must {
                                    term(tech:1)                                    
                                }
                                must {
                                    term(country:1)
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Any suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The supported Groovy DSL is very similar to the JSON.

```
{
  indices "index"
  types "type"
  source {
    query {
      filtered {
        query {
          match {
            project = "ABC"
          }
        }
        filter {
          bool {
            must [
              {
                term {
                  subtech = 2
                }
              },
              {
                term {
                  tech = 1
                }
              },
              {
                term {
                  country = 1
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In your Groovy version, I noticed that your filters were different than the JSON ones. Specifically, your terms from the JSON are for `subtech`, `tech`, and `country`. For the Groovy API, you're filtering against `agent`, `subtech`, and `country`.

You're also reassigning the `must` within the `bool` rather than assigning it an array of filters.

```
must {
  term(agent:1)
}
must {
  term(subtech:2)
}
must {
  term(country:1)
}
```

Refer to the above example to see how it should be done. It's the reassignment/calling of `must` that is trouble here. Passing in the `Map` is valid, although I'd personally recommend more closely mirroring the JSON.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I fixed the example and the result is the same :(.

Comment: I try with your example and I have an exception: 
`org.elasticsearch.search.SearchParseException: [index][4]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{"query":{"filtered":{"query":{"match":{"project":"ABC"}},"filter":{"bool":{"must.getAt":[{"term":{"subtech":2}},{"term":{"tech":1}},{"term":{"country":1}}]}}}}}]]`

Comment: Which version of the Groovy client are you using? Also, try changing it to `must = [` from `must [`.

Comment: I have groovy 2.4.3.
I changed must = [ for must [ and all works fine :).
thank you so much!!!

Comment: I'm going to push out a patch for needing the `=` soon. That shouldn't be necessary, but I'm glad that there was a workaround!